# Version control of chef nodes and roles

Tags: chef, version-control

Is it good practice to version control the nodes and roles when using chef?  If so, what is a good way to do it?

It looks likes one should be able to take a tree of JSON files created using `chef_server_backup.rb` and simply check it into VC.  Are there better alternatives?

**Update**

It turns out that checking in the JSON produced by `chef_server_backup.rb` is **not** a good solution.  The problem is that the JSON produced by the script is not stable.  Each time the hashes come out in a different order and the resulting files are totally different to the previous versions ... even though they means the same thing when parsed as JSON.  I would be better of just saving compress tarballs.

(But if I could canonicalize the JSON files by ordering the attributes ... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try and keep as much of my configuration as possible as JSON files and update chef-server with `knife [noun] from file name.json`. I started with the repository at https://github.com/opscode/chef-repo and I keep all of JSON files in the appropriate directories. You can do the same with YAML or Ruby files too. Use the `show` command, like `knife role show apache2 -Fj > roles/apache2.json` to create files from existing data already on a chef-server.

Some of the benefits of a "from file"-based approach are:

- Relatively easy to move between Hosted Chef and Private Chef
- You can test with chef-solo using existing role files, data_bag items, etc
- Track deltas between changes via `git diff`, and view history of more than just cookbook versions
- Redundancy of data: if your Private Chef server or Hosted Chef is unavailable, you still have all of your infrastructure configuration

The only thing not in [opscode/chef-repo](https://github.com/opscode/chef-repo) are node files. You can export/import nodes from files too, but it's generally not recommended because nodes should be disposable. I like how [Nathen Harvey](http://www.nathenharvey.com/) once said: "think of nodes as cattle, not pets."